# CSS: Footer crashing into content area

Tags: css, position, css-float

I've been trying to solve this using all sorts of methods, including display, clear, float and position and nothing seems to change this.

Basically what is happening is my footer on this homepage (http://writtenpalette.com/) is crashing into the #content div. It seems to be respecting the #sidebar height instead of the entire content height.

Like I said I've tried all sorts of methods....none of which seemed to have worked. So here's my CSS for the main sections to see what might be the issue:

```
body.home #content {
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: -3%;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background: #65254A;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<div id="content" class="hfeed masonry" style="position: relative; height: 0px;">
```

to

```
<div id="content" class="hfeed masonry" style="position: relative; height: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by validating the page:

https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwrittenpalette.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Then use a web inspector to pursue the positioning.

Also, use HTML5.